# What is wrong in my CSS code?

Tags: css

What is wrong with my code? I am using a PHP file for header and then I am including it where is needed.

This is the CSS I have:

```
header {
    margin-top:0;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("slike/dekorativni.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
 }
```

When I set the background to some color it is showing colored background but image won't show.

Is it OK to put `!DOCTYPE` HTML in a PHP file inside an echo?

Comment: If background color works, are you 100% positive that image exists exactly where you think it does? that path his relative to the css file.

Comment: Are you using `background-color` or `background`?

Comment: why the php tag? there's only css here. Edit: to which that was removed in an edit.

Comment: Maybe `header` is a class, so `.header`?

Comment: I have removed the php tag add it back when you have a coding that have to do with php

Comment: that's what I was thinking also @Halcyon

Comment: @Funker you need to update your question to contain the HTML for all this.

Comment: @Halcyon background colors works, image is the problem

Comment: *"it's show colored background but image whant show."* - If this is a path issue and is php related also, then check your path and check for errors. *"is it ok to put !DOCTYPE html in php file inside echo?"* - You've no code to support this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Setting background-image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649576/css-setting-background-image-in-css)

Comment: As it stand we don't know your folder structure thus making it difficult for us.. check the browser console for errors

Comment: When including PHP files the included files should not have header section. Please check the example: http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page

Comment: i can't provide you my header.php because it wont show it, i tried but it wont! it is look some like this <?php echo' <!DOCTYPEhtml> rest of the code...'?>  everything insite echo is within double quotes.

Comment: everything is accepting when i am change css except background-image. and i am use background-image:url("path/image.jpg"); and path is ok

Comment: tnx @CarlosMartins for tip but my background image still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to Relative URLs. It may happen that your included file is not loading the css or the image path after including is not working. If you use Relative URL to the image path it must work. Please check also if your css is being load in the included file, check if fonts and other formats are working.

Comment: i reorganize everything and now is working, i am guessing that problem was with image path or name i am not sure.